# How to write Groovy script to zip a folder from soapUI?

Tags: groovy

I have a folder in C drive with some files in it and am searching for groovy script to zip that file. Can any one plz help how to write groovy script to zip that folder I need to use this groovy script in SoapUI.

Thanks,

Latiff.

Answer (score 1):

This would work (Credits to [Solomon Duskis's solution](http://www.jroller.com/Solomon/entry/zipping_files_with_groovy))

```
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream

//Your folder here
File topDir = new File('c:\\FilesToZip'); 
//Your zip file here
ZipOutputStream zipOutput = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream('c:\\zipfile.zip')); 

int topDirLength = topDir.absolutePath.length()

topDir.eachFileRecurse
{ file ->
    def relative = file.absolutePath.substring(topDirLength).replace('\\', '/') 
    if ( file.isDirectory() && !relative.endsWith('/'))
    {
        relative += "/"
    }  

    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(relative)
    entry.time = file.lastModified()
    zipOutput.putNextEntry(entry)

    if( file.isFile() )
    {
        zipOutput << new FileInputStream(file)
    }
}

zipOutput.close()
```